# Use of WHERE SAME AND operator in SAS DATA step

Tags: sas

I am a beginner of SAS language learning. I learn that there are five Special_where operators we use in SAS. Among them one is WHERE SAME AND operator. Could anyone help me how will I use that operator with an example

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

You can use `WHERE` statement in DATA steps and also probably more usefully in PROC steps. The `WHERE SAME AND` which also perhaps easier to remember under it's other name of `WHERE ALSO` will let you use multiple statements to add more restrictions.

This is easy to see with an example like:

```
proc means data=sashelp.class ;
  where sex='M';
  where also age > 12 ;
  var height;
run;
```

because SAS will echo the resulting subsetting condition to the LOG.

```
1334  proc means data=sashelp.class ;
1335    where sex='M';
1336    where also age > 12 ;
NOTE: WHERE clause has been augmented.
1337    var height;
1338  run;

NOTE: Multiple concurrent threads will be used to summarize data.
NOTE: There were 6 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
      WHERE (sex='M') and (age>12);
```

Note that is you use both `WHERE` and `WHERE ALSO` statements the order makes a difference.

```
1339  proc means data=sashelp.class ;
1340    where also age > 12 ;
NOTE: WHERE clause has been augmented.
1341    where sex='M';
NOTE: WHERE clause has been replaced.
1342    var height;
1343  run;

NOTE: Multiple concurrent threads will be used to summarize data.
NOTE: There were 10 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
      WHERE sex='M';
```

But you can always just use `WHERE ALSO` for all of the statements and then the order doesn't matter.

```
1344  proc means data=sashelp.class ;
1345    where also age > 12 ;
NOTE: WHERE clause has been augmented.
1346    where also sex='M';
NOTE: WHERE clause has been augmented.
1347    var height;
1348  run;

NOTE: Multiple concurrent threads will be used to summarize data.
NOTE: There were 6 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
      WHERE (age>12) and (sex='M');
```

Comment: Thanks Tom for the answer. Could you please provide any example with WHERE SAME AND operator

Comment: WHERE ALSO and WHERE SAME AND are two names for the same thing.

Comment: Hello Tom, DATA A;
  SET SASHELP.CLASS;
  WHERE SEX ="M" AND AGE<20;
  WHERE SAME AND HEIGHT<50;
RUN;    This program is not working. Could you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: That program works fine. There just aren't any cases that meet all three criteria. Min(HEIGHT) for males is 57.3.